# How to create domain entity using data received from other bounded context?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have scenario where i will get a information from other bounded context through messaging queue, I need to build the domain entity using the information received from message queue(construction of entity may vary depending on the information). Now, do i need to create the domain entity in infrastructure level and modify in domain layer? (or) Do i need to bring the message queue data into domain layer services and create domain entity using message queue data information.

Comment: Read about Bounded Context integration and Anti-corruption layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably have the subscriber to the message queue fire a domain event that contains the data received from the other bounded context. An event handler for this event will then create the relevant Entity for this context.

In case where it is needed, I can potentially fire another event that let's this bounded context know that the entity was created.

Comment: Creation of entity also involves some business logic, do i need to keep that in event handler?

Comment: Beyond a simple creation of thr Entity using a Factory or Builder then using thr Entity's Repository to persist it, the event handlers can call domain services if needed.

Answer (score 0):

At the infrastructure level where the queue job is actioned, instead of raising a domain event as jett suggested, sending a command to create the Aggregate seems more reasonable in my mind. Once constructed, the AR then fires the domain event